# Getting started on ASP.NET AJAX with jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am currently using the ScriptManager and whatever comes with it, but I'd like to manage my AJAX in jQuery, because I'm about to start working on something rather important and I want it to be as efficient as possible.

From what it appears, jQuery AJAX fails to reach the server, for a reason unknown to me.

Is there anything else I need to use except for the standard jQuery 1.9.1 library?

EDIT:

HTML && Javascript:

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="_Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="jQueryAjax._Default1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
  <title>Calling a page method with jQuery</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // Add the page method call as an onclick handler for the div.
            $("#Result").click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "_Default.aspx/GetDate",
                    data: "{}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (msg) {
                        // Replace the div's content with the page method's return.
                        $("#Result").text(msg.d);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="Result">Click here for the time.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace jQueryAjax
{
    public partial class _Default1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        [WebMethod]
        public static string GetDate()
        {
            return DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've posted the code that I'm currently using. You can see it at http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Comment: This is the first time in 2 years when something doesn't work, and I don't know why, and I have no idea what I do, but it works, and I don't know why. I'd like to apologize to the moderator (I guess that's what you call them here) for having to clean up my mess, so, sorry about that. Problem solved.